# How to add dotted grid lines in Excel charts with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, charts

I'm working on a C# based Excel generation project but am stuck on the graph generation part.

Is there any option available in C# to generate a graph with a grid of dotted lines rather than the usual solid ones?

Comment: see the example http://tinypic.com/r/vvzgx/8

Comment: yes, sorry for that, I don't have enough reputation to add picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
xAxis = (Excel.Axis)myChart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);              
xAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
xAxis.MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineDashDot;
```

This works for me with using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Chart Types:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489233(v=vs.140).aspx

The one you probably want is to add major gridlines to your chart  area and change the style to Point.

Chart Point Style:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456684(v=vs.140).aspx

You then give it X,Y coordinates to plot.

To alter the GridLine style though, you need to use MajorGrid.Style

Example:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle 
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle
```

LineDashStyle maybe solid, dotted, and so forth.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.grid.linedashstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

LineDashStyle inherits ChartDashStyle enumerations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartdashstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Final Example:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle.Dot
```

Comment: I'm using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**, I cant acess the ChartAreas[0]

Comment: It is similar only you need to "Get" ChartArea a different way.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chartarea(v=office.15).aspx


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.chartarea.aspx

Comment: Can you please explain little more, or can we use ChartType = (xlXYScatter like option)?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure but it says you can use: _Chart.ChartArea

To get the ChartArea and it has those properties mentioned.

Comment: The question is asking for Interop not MS's chart library.